# Rendering html code from database to Laravel blade view

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to retrieve HTML code that is written in the Laravel Blade template from the database to my Laravel Blade view. I was able to retrieve and show the web view however, the blade functions like `{{ route() }}` and `{{ asset() }}` are not working. It's only getting html view and not translating the blade functions.
Here's my Controller code:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $home_page = Site::where('page_name', 'page_home')->get();

        return view('index', ['home_page' => $home_page]);
    }
```

and here is the blade view code:

```
    @foreach ($home_page as $home)
        {!! html_entity_decode($home->content_one) !!}
        {!! html_entity_decode($home->content_two) !!}
        {!! html_entity_decode($home->content_three) !!}
    @endforeach
```

I removed the functions and wrote them like HTML codes then it worked, but to do that, I have to edit my whole website. So, I wanted to know how can I retrieve HTML code from the database and make it work like a real blade view.

Comment: The template you've shared does not use `route()` or `asset()` after all. Also, are you sure this problem is in any way related to MySQL?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this using the `render` method provided by the `Blade` facade - https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't think the problem is related to MySQL because I'm able to retrieve the data properly. My HTML code is written in Blade template so, I did use the `route()` and `asset()` functions.

Comment: @user1191247 I have multiple functions in my controller so, how do I use the `render()` function?

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: This is not what Blade is for ... Blade has to get compiled to PHP and then that PHP has to be executed

Comment: I wouldn't have asked how to make those functions work like real laravel blade view if didn't write them in my code. Anyways, sorry, I've edit my post.

Comment: @lagbox are there any ways to compile after retrieving from the database?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a raw HTML threw variables should be fine but injecting a direct calls to blade are not really a thing.

As the page is compiled it runs the functions first then prints out the pass down variables from the controller.

So the blade will never execute it as it life cycle is already pass threw that point.

Comment: I tried the html_entity_decode() function in controller too, but it didn't work

Comment: That is not what is happening here. You are trying to pass down a function call threw a controller variable to blade. 
That call will not be executed as you already passed a point of blade engine trying to execute all the functions already and by the time your variable with `{{ route() }}` appears in the blade its already to late for it to be executed.

Comment: So, is there any way to load blade view from database with functions?

Comment: no there is not sadly.